# Wrong output of after I sum the data from database

Tags: php, mysql

Let say I wan to sum up the Duration in my leave table and with condition Leave_Type = 'Annual' and Status = 'Approved'

My **database**

```
table leave
{Leave_ID(PK), Leave_Type, Status, Duration, Emp_ID(FK)}

table employee
{Emp_ID(PK), Emp_Name}
```

I use the following code to sum the Duration

```
$aid=$_SESSION["eid"];

$Annual = mysql_query("select SUM(Duration)

FROM `leave`

WHERE leave.Leave_Type = 'Annual' and leave.Status = 'Approved' 
and leave.Emp_ID = employee.Emp_ID and leave.Emp_ID = $aid");
```

The way i display the output

```
<td><?php echo $Annual;?></td>
```

But the output I get is something like "Resourse id#4". That's not the output I want and it should be the total sum of duration. Is there is any problem with `mysql_query` or the way i print my output?

Comment: What is the `type` of the `duration` column? Integer, Datetime?

Comment: Your query filters by `employee.Emp_ID` but doesn't read `employee`. It's impossible that it returns any output: it must be crashing.

Comment: Actually, I think it will work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong the output!

```
$AnnualData = mysql_fetch_assoc($Annual);
```

Than the output:

```
<td><?php echo $AnnualData['SUM(Duration)'];?></td>
```

If you want you can add an alias to the sum statement like this ( in the sql query ):

```
SUM(Duration) AS total
```

and than output like this:

```
<td><?php echo $AnnualData['total'];?></td>
```

Comment: Better yet, put a name on the field. `SUM(Duration) as leaveDuration` and retrieve it as `$AnnualData['leaveDuration']`

Answer (score 0):

You're only running the query, you need to fetch the data.

Change mysql_query to `mysqli_query` (the former one is deprecated) and then use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($Annual)`

Answer (score 0):

You should add;

```
$annual2 = mysql_fetch_array($annual);
```

then

```
<?PHP echo $annual2['Duration']; ?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This will not work as you are selected the **SUM** of `Duration` and not `Duration` itself

Comment: Okay then, add $annual3 = SUM($annual2['duration'];

Comment: I'm sorry but no, look at the query and the answer `Lwyrn` gave earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=mysql_fetch_array($Annual);

echo $query[0];
```

it will print what you want exactly...